# Dynamically acessing a built-in type object by name

Tags: python, module, dynamically-generated, built-in-types

In Python, it is possible to dynamically access a *class* object by name with `getattr`:

```
getattr(module, "<class_name>")
```

How can I do that for *built-in type* objects (`int`, `str`, `list`, etc.)?

I would like to use the same trick, but I don't know in which module built-in types are defined.

Comment: what do yoy think of ```dir(builtins)```

Comment: @KartikeyaSharma Nice.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found what I was looking for by myself:

```
import builtins

getattr(builtins, "<type_name>")
```

*Note.* — Do not use the `__builtins__` module as it is an implementation detail (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html) of the CPython interpreter.

Comment: @DroidX86 Thanks, I have updated my answer with the public `builtins` module (since the `__builtins__` module is an implementation detail).

Comment: Instead of `getattr`, you can more simply access the desired attribute as `builtins.<class_name>`, for example: `builstins.str`, `builtins.int`, `builstins.bool`, etc. No?

Comment: @InonPeled And even more simply with `<type_name>`: `str`, `int`, `bool`, so I wouldn't have asked this question. But my question was about *dynamic* access: given a type *name* (a string), how can I access the type *object*.